# How do you push the latest head/master into SVN from GIT without all the history?

Tags: git, svn

I'm dealing with two repositories.  A remote server running SVN and my local git repo.

I've got my head/master branch to where I want it after several edits.  Now I just want to push the latest copy of what's in git into an empty SVN directory with a single commit, without the 100 commits and all the history to get it in place and from that point on in the future git svn dcommit.

I did some searching but everything that I turned up seemed to find ways of keeping the entire git repo history, I'd like to push with just a single commit and then `git svn dcommit` from there on in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to take a look at `git rebase -i` http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

This will allow you to squash a branch history down to one commit message.

If you have two branches

- master
- *working_branch (this is the branch where you have a few commits)

While still in working_branch you would run `git rebase -i master`. From here you can choose which commits to "squash", "reword", etc. Once you have completed the rebase. You would then `git checkout master` and `git merge working_branch` back into master.

From master then do `git svn dcommit`